# Display image inside a 'div' and resize to a specific size

Tags: javascript, html, image, resize-image

I am developing a form and I am having some problems with image display and resize.

To make it better understood, I leave you with the image of what I have now, and what I want to achieve.

[What I have now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vwetD.png)

[What I want to achieve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vdZNb.png)

Note that what I want is to resize the image and make it less tall, but not less wide, and centre it in the middle of the **div** parent.

And this is a part of the HTML file:

```
<div class="container rounded" style="background-color: rgb(228, 225, 225);">
    <br>
    <form id="editProductForm" class="needs-validation" novalidate style="padding: 15px 40px;">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <div class="row" style="margin-top: 5px;">
                    <div class="col-sm-9">
                        <div class="input-group mb-3">
                            //input group Número de producto
                        </div>
                        <div class="input-group" style="width: 100%;">
                            //input group Visible
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-3"></div>
                </div>
                <br>
                <br>
                <br>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="input-group mb-3">
                        //input group Nombre del producto *
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-5">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-4"></div>
                    <div class="col-sm-8" style="padding: 0px; text-align: center;">
                        <img class="img" id="productimage">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row" style="margin-top: 5px;">
                    <div class="col-sm-4"></div>
                    <div class="col-sm-8" style="padding: 0px; text-align: end;">
                        <input type="file" class="form-control" id="inputImage" accept="image/*">
                    </div>
                </div> 
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-1"></div> 
        </div>
    </form>            
</div>
```

**EDIT: Adding CSS**

```
*{
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
  }

span.title { 
    background: #0bbe83;
    color: white;
    font-weight: bold;  
} 

.img{
    width: 70%;
}

/*To show the borders of the cell*/
.row > div {
    background: lightgrey;
    border: 1px solid grey;
}
```

**EDIT: Solution**

```
.img{
    width: 70%;
    height: 65%;
    object-fit: cover;
}
```

[Result of changing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c1AQo.png)

I hope someone can help me, please.
Thanks

Comment: Can you update your question with your css

Comment: I have added in the edited part

Comment: Okay... since you want to reduce the height of the image without reducing the width, you have to set the height you intend having, like `height: 65%`, this will result in the image being stretched or squeezed. So you have to add `object-fit: cover;` to the image style.

Comment: If you don’t understand, let me know

Comment: I have modified the image style as you said: `.img{
    height: 65%;
    object-fit: cover;
}` but now the result is not what I have expected. I edited the question to show you the result.

Comment: I used `height: 65%` as an example... because you said you want to make the image less tall... I also didn’t say u should remove the `width: 70%` declaration on the image style too

Comment: Nice, it works, thanks